# Does Kafka consumer can be implemented in android app. I am getting error "Failed resolution of: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory"

Tags: android, apache-kafka

I am trying to integrate Kafka consumer in android application. Integration part is done and application is building but when I run the application it got crash and throw error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory"

Here is the code block

Gradle file is given below

```
  // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

  buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:7.0.0"
       // classpath 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.3.1'
    }
}
plugins {
    id "java"
    id "idea"
    id "eclipse"
    id "com.google.cloud.tools.jib" version "3.3.1"
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
}
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
version = "0.0.1"


apply plugin: "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow"
dependencies {
    implementation "org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:2.0.6"
    implementation "org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.3.1"
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.13.2"
    testImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.2'
}

test {
    testLogging {
        outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
        showStandardStreams = true
        exceptionFormat = "full"
    }
}
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                "Class-Path": configurations.compileClasspath.collect { it.getName() }.join(" "),
                "Main-Class": "com.nec.jp.kafkconsumer.KafkaConsumerApplication"
        )
    }
}

shadowJar {
    archiveBaseName = "kafka-consumer-application-standalone"
    archiveClassifier = ''
}
```

---

```
     String bootStrapServer = "192.168.1.7:9092";


     String groupId = "Group99";
       final Properties consumerAppProps = new Properties();
        consumerAppProps.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
 bootStrapServer);
        consumerAppProps.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
 StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        consumerAppProps.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
 StringDeserializer.class.getName());
         consumerAppProps.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        consumerAppProps.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,
 "earliest");
        KafkaConsumer<Object, Object> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(consumerAppProps);
```

Comment: Duplicate post is about producer, but same answer applies. Use HTTP clients, instead. Kafka isn't meant to be exposed to the open internet, as is common with services for mobile apps. You can use Confluent REST Proxy as a middleware layer

Comment: Unrelated, but jib Gradle plugin is for Docker containers. Why use for an Android app?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Does it mean, Kafka could not be integrated with the Android application?

Comment: Not directly in Android by just adding the dependency in Gradle. To access any Kafka Producer you need to write a server side code that consumes the producer using KafkaConsumer and then exposes the results of through HTTP REST, WebSockets or gRPC.

Comment: Thanks, @Prajjwal, but someone told me that we can add Javax dependency locally, is there any room to achieve this?

Comment: Even if you can add the dependencies and make it work for Android, because as explained by @OneCricketeer and me exposing Kafka producers over an unstable mobile connection is not recommended and not standard practice. You are not only exposing a Kafka producer that anyone can now consume, you also have to deal with error checking and error correction due to unstable nature of mobile networks.

Comment: Kafka can use TLS and protect the connection with certificates in other ways, but that's besides the point. The main problem is with network connectivity that Kafka clients depend on to be fast and resilient. MQTT and HTTP are more common protocols for mobile/embedded devices with limited network capabilities, and you can forward that traffic to a Kafka cluster **server side**

Answer (score 0):

Kafka uses the classes in the `javax.management.*` package which are not included in Android.([Source](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7025)) You are better off trying to expose whatever producer you intend to consume as REST API, WebSocket or as a gRPC.